Export Simulink model workspace variable in FMU
I'm trying to export a Matlab/Simulink model into fmu, but some variables (defined in the model workspace, not in the base one) are marked as not tunable so the exporting process produces no set/get methods for these variables.
I tried manually editing these variable in the tunable parameter tab but does not work.
Any suggestion?

How do you generate your FMU? with FMI-Kit from Dassault Systems or with the native FMU generation from Mathworks?
